# Using template arguments in std::function

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated function, that picks a vector or list element based on an algorithms specified by the caller:

```
template<typename It>
void Foo(It begin, It end, std::function<It(It, It)> GetElement)
{
    It element = GetElement(begin, end);
}
```

How can I call this function using a lambda expression?

My first approach was

```
Foo(v.begin(), 
    v.end(), 
    [v](? , ? ) {return v.begin(); });
```

But the I obiously got stuck at the argument part, which is symbolized by the question marks...

Comment: `It` is not deducible for `std::function<It(It, It)>` from lambda. You probably want concept which we don't have yet :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**C++11**:

```
Foo(v.begin(), 
    v.end(), 
    [v](decltype(v.begin()) a, decltype(v.begin()) b) { return v.begin(); });
```

---

**C++14**:

```
Foo(v.begin(), 
    v.end(), 
    [v](auto a, auto b) { return v.begin(); });
```

If you don't care about the arguments `a` and `b`, you can use: `[v](auto...){ return v.begin(); }` instead as suggested by **skypjack** in the comments.

---

Also, I suggest passing the lambda as a template parameter **unless you have a good reason to use `std::function`**:

```
template<typename It, typename F>
void Foo(It begin, It end, F&& GetElement)
{
    It element = GetElement(begin, end);
}
```

I wrote an article that's related to the subject: 
[**"Passing functions to functions"**](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/passing_functions_to_functions.html)

It contains some benchmarks that show how much assembly is generated for `std::function` compared to a template parameter and other solutions.

Comment: Isn't `[v](auto...) { return v.begin(); }`  just fine? You don't use neither `a` nor `b` anyway.

Comment: @skypjack: definitely, I (maybe incorrectly) assumed that the `{ return v.begin(); }` body was just a placeholder. I also wanted to give the most general way of matching both arguments.

Comment: How would I call the templated function version?

Comment: @user1934212: exactly in the same way

Comment: or with `std::forward<F>(GetElement)(begin, end);` for some purists ;-)